# Bash storing grep into a variable

Tags: regex, bash, grep

So i need to find a word count for the amount of words in a certain file

So in my code I have

```
grep -c "word" file
```

(that outputs the amount of instances we see in a file)

but is there any way to have it stored to a variable?

I tried

```
a = grep -c "word" file
```

and then `echo $a`

as well as

```
$a = grep -c "word file
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Are you trying to store output of grep in a variable or grep command itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
a=`grep -c "word" file`
```

Note the use of backquotes `` ` ``.  The equivalent syntax `$(...)` should also work.

Comment: You mean `$( )`, `${...}` gives the content of the variable "...".

Comment: You should use `$(...)` since back tics is old and obsoleted.

Comment: @Jotne: Totally agree with you. I'll update my answer. My problem was that I just moved to `bash` two years ago, thankfully, after being stuck with `csh` for almost twenty years. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can store grep command line into a variable as this:

```
a='grep -c "word" file'
```

and later call it as:

```
bash -c "$a"
```

But **better solution** is to use BASH arrays:

```
arr=(grep -c "word" file)
${arr[@]}
```

Comment: Perhaps need backquotes `\`` rather than single quotes `'`in the first example.

Comment: Actually we can use single quotes since there nothing to expand otherwise we would need to use double quotes.

Comment: I believe he wants to store the output of the command, not the command itself.

Comment: @Kevin: You might be right, but it is not clear and question title also says `storing grep into a variable`

Comment: I agree, it's ambiguous.